# AMD stock fan very loud

Tags: amd-ryzen, cpu-cooler

When using my PC my AMD fan is always at 100% and makes a noise similar to 1:43 in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2m9l-nDd1fw&t=100s. How do I fix this?

Comment: You replace it.. that would be my guess.

Comment: The stock fans aren't always that great. If it's the CPU fan, you can try installing something like MSI Afterburner or a similar software to set a fan speed profile. If it's a case fan you can get a fan controller, try installing Speed Fan, or getting a higher quality fan like a Cougar Vortex.